# Map Jackson json attribute to corresponding xml element

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I am using Jackson `objectMapper` to read JSON to JsonNode, Then I am using `xmlMapper` to serialize this to XML.

I'd like to set an XML attribute value by parsing a `JSON` attribute with tag "@". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EXAMPLE JSON:

```
{
  "response" : {
    "label" : {
      "@data" : "someValue"
    }
  }
}
```

NEED TO MAP TO XML:

```
<response>
  <label data="someValue" />
</response>
```

This is what I can get right now:

```
<response>
  <label>
     <@data>someValue</@data>
  </label>
</response>
```

CODE:

```
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(JSON); 
xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(root);
```

Answer (score 3):

well, I found a solution that produces the required output. However, I am not sure if this is an optimal solution, in a sense that it requires custom inner classes to be able to specify the annotations that tell the mappers how to parse.

```
import java.util.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

public class JSONTest
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            String jsonInput = "{  \"response\" : {    \"label\" : {      \"@data\" : \"someValue\"    }  }}";

            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeFactory tf = om.getTypeFactory();
            JavaType mapType = tf.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, response.class);
            Map<String, response> map = (Map<String, response>)om.readValue(jsonInput, mapType);

            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            String ss = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(map.get("response"));
            System.out.println(ss);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class response {
        public Label label;
    }

    public static class Label {
        @JsonProperty("@data")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        public String data;
    }
}
```

output:

`<response><label data="someValue"/></response>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. but is there any way to set the data attribute not by creating an java object, as the json input structure are not fixed, is there any jackson API to use to set attribute?

Comment: @xuyanli Did you ever figure this out? I need something similar and don't want to make POJO classes. My guess is extending Jackson's XML node deserializer.